# Quebec language law and "French First" requirement

Tags: canada, business, software, employment

Suppose I am developing an application for company A which will be used by A's employees worldwide. A has offices in Quebec, Canada. I am aware that local laws exist in Quebec which protect workers rights there to work in French.

As part of the process of internationalizing the application, which of the following are required by that law, if any:

- The default language is French
- The default language can be English, but it must be possible for a user who speaks only French to change the language to French
- The default language can be English, and it may be required that the user know some English or to have taken specific training to know how to change the language
- same as above, but no training

Also, to what degree does the law require localization of non-alphabetic information such as: large numbers, dates, currencies, punctuation, and the like, where a French-speaking employee in Quebec would customarily use conventions different from those adopted by an English-speaking software developer in America?

Comment: Interesting question! A French speaker myself (although I come from Toronto), I've got to say that it's an interesting scenario. I would expect that support be provided to French-speakers, but I wouldn't expect to see a default language. I'd expect that your third option would be required. Speaking of which, is the internationalized external or internal? I would assume that would greatly change an answer - workers don't use the application, they use the source code, which provides a different environment. I'll see if I can find something on this :)

Comment: Would it not be legal to head-quarter the company in another region than Quebec?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Where does "workers don't use the application, they use the source code…" come from, please? To you does "workers" mean "developers" or "users"? To me, it's fairly clear that developers work on source code and users work with the application. 

In any case, did you find something on that?